# res.write not working properly. It's showing output including HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, httpwebresponse

I'm making a simple web application using API's and express.
But I am getting different output than expected. My output contains text including **HTML** tags.

**Here's my code.**

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  const url =
    'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&units=metric&appid=0333cb6bfed722ca09f1062ec1ea9ca1';
  https.get(url, function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode + ' OK');
    response.on('data', function(data) {
      const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
      const temp = weatherData.main.temp;
      const desc = weatherData.weather[0].description;
      const icon = weatherData.weather[0].icon;
      const imageURL = 'http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/' + icon + '@2x.png';

      res.write('<h3>The weather is currently ' + desc + '</h3>');
      //res.write('<img src=' + imageURL + '>');
      res.write(
        '<h1>The temperature in London is ' +
          '<span>' +
          temp +
          '</span> ° Celsius.</h1>'
      );
      res.send();
    });
  });
  //res.send('server is up!!!');
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Server started!!!');
});
```

**output:**
[image]

Comment: which article you are following to achieve res.write in that way?

Comment: I'm following udemy course of complete web development 2020 by Angela Yu.

Comment: I also had this issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set header:`res.set("Content-Type", "text/html");`

> **Suggestion:** use template string :(

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const app = express();

const url =
  "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&units=metric&appid=0333cb6bfed722ca09f1062ec1ea9ca1";
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  https.get(url, response => {
    response.on("data", data => {
      const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
      const temp = weatherData.main.temp;
      const { description, icon } = weatherData.weather[0];
      const imageURL = `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${icon}@2x.png`;

      res.set("Content-Type", "text/html");
      //OR
      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");

      res.send(`
      <h3>The weather is currently ${description}</h3>
      <img src="${imageURL}">
      <h1>The temperature in London is <span>${temp}</span> ° Celsius.</h1>
      `);
    });
  });
  //res.send('server is up!!!');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server started!!!");
});
```

Comment: where to put this following?

Comment: @VipulSinha Please check updated code. Use ES6 template string. code looks so ugly :-D

Comment: NP> I have a cleanup little bit. Please check

Answer (score 0):

```
const express=require("express");
const https=require("https");
const app=express();

app.get("/",function(req,res){
const url="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=d44d8ad5bbf91d43d54c12a154921930&q=surat&units=metric"
    https.get(url,function(response){
        console.log(response.statusCode);

        response.on("data",function(data){
        
            const weatherData=JSON.parse(data)
          
            const temp=weatherData.main.temp
            
            const weatherDescription=weatherData.weather[0].description
            

            const feels_like=weatherData.main.feels_like
           
            res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
            res.write("<h3>The Weather is currently "+weatherDescription+"</h3>");
            res.write("<h1>The temperature in Surat is :"+temp+" Degree Celcius</h1>");
            res.send() 

        })
    })
    //res.send("Server is up and running")
})


app.listen(3000,function(){
    
    console.log("Server is rinning on port 3000.");
})
```

Comment: use this 4 line it will help up:-
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
            res.write("<h3>The Weather is currently "+weatherDescription+"</h3>");
            res.write("<h1>The temperature in Surat is :"+temp+" Degree Celcius</h1>");
            res.send()

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Just put res.set or res.setHeader with content type before res.write will give you the solution.

```
res.set("Content-Type", "text/html");
res.write('<h3>The weather is currently ' + desc + '</h3>');
// or
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
res.write('<h3>The weather is currently ' + desc + '</h3>');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const app = express();
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=f7b456d9c3a2e6e39c6f1ac945c5a16b&units=metric";
    https.get(url, function (response) {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        response.on("data", function (data) {
            {
                const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
                const temp=weatherData.main.temp;
                const weatherDescription=weatherData.weather[0].description;
                res.set("Content-Type", "text/html");
                console.log(weatherDescription);
                res.write("<h3>The weather is currently "+weatherDescription+" </h3>")
                res.write("<h1>The temperature in London is "+temp+" degrees Celcius</h1>")
                res.send();
            }
        })
    });
})
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
})
```

The line res.set("Content-Type", "text/html") is setting the Content-Type header of the response to indicate that the response body will be in HTML format. This line ensures that the browser or client receiving the response knows how to interpret and display the content correctly.

The res.set() function in Express is used to set response headers. In this case, setting the Content-Type header to "text/html" informs the client that the response will be in HTML format.

When the client receives the response, it checks the Content-Type header and processes the response accordingly. In this case, since the Content-Type is set to "text/html", the client (typically a web browser) will interpret the response as HTML and render it accordingly.

By setting the Content-Type header to "text/html", the browser knows that it should expect HTML content, and it will render the response as HTML, displaying the weather information correctly with the appropriate formatting.