# express not rendering the html

Tags: node.js, api, express, backend

I am trying to send information back to the webpage to the user using ".write" and then when i use the ".send" method to send the response present in ".write" it doesn't render the html.

express code:-

```
 res.write("<h2>The weather seems like" + weatherDescription + "</h2>");
         res.write("<h1>The temprature in banglore is  " + temprature + " degree celcius.</h1><br>");
         res.send();
```

how it gets rendered in the browser:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [res.write not working properly. It's showing output including HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60919157/res-write-not-working-properly-its-showing-output-including-html-tags)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the content type before writing back the HTML

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
```